# Parameter expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying the following code in shell for Parameter Expansion

```
#!/bin/sh
count
echo ${count:-60}
echo ${count:=120}
echo $count
echo ${count:+80}
x = 'The host name is google'
echo ${#x}
```

Output

```
./test_varexp.sh: line 2: count: command not found
60
120
120
80
./test_varexp.sh: line 7: x: command not found
0
```

With the above code and output in context i have following questions;

1. The parameter expansion with '=' symbol should set the value of count to 120, which is also seen as happening when we printed the value of count , but in the next line it is getting overwritten when i use the same with "+" which should only check for existence. Can somebody explain this anomaly? or Can somebody explain if count is actually existing or not?
2. The parameter expansion for `${#x}` is not at all working. Can someone tell me if there is any syntax error?

I am trying the above code

```
[root@dtltrhel5u8 shellscripts]# uname -a
Linux dtltrhel5u8 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:17:51 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing a number of issues here. The shell will tokenize your input on whitespace (or generally on `IFS`, but respecting any quoting) and look for assignments and commands, in that order. If the first token contains `=` then it is an assignment, which may be followed by further assignments or a command. If not, then it's a command, and any remaining parameters are command arguments. (There used to be a  time when assignments could also follow a command, and there are ways to make modern shells behave like that,  for backwards compatibility; but let's just ignore that sidetrack.)

So `count` is a command, which obviously doesn't exist. Perhaps you meant `count=` to define the variable without a  value (this is  distinct from leaving it unset).

The expansion `${count:+80}` produces the value `80` if the variable is set and nonempty; this is precisely what you are getting. If the variable were empty or unset, an empty string would be substituted instead.

If you wanted to assign a value to `x`, again, the equals sign and the value needs to be part of the first token; so

```
x='The host name is google'
```

Once the assignment works, the string's length will no longer be zero.

Comment: `${#x}` isn't a `bash` extension. All the parameter expansions in the question are [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: @chepner Right you are; removed that passage

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is easily explained by the documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Specifically, `${count:+80}` returns nothing if `count` is unset, and `80` if it is set.  The value of `count` is still 120.

Your other syntax error is that you shouldn't put spaces around the `=`.

```
x='The host name is google'
echo ${#x}
```

prints `23`.

Comment: Thank you every one for clarifying :)